# New meta posts no longer appear in right side of main site

Tags: support, feature-request

I remember the new mathematica.meta posts used to appear in right side of the main site, but now it's not the case:

[image]

↑ *Who cares about this?*

This makes the mathematica.meta site deserted.

Can the old layout be brought back?

Comment: Unfortunately I think a meta post needs like 5 votes now before it'll appear there, leading to a vicious cycle of lack of engagement with meta. This does seem to mirror the lack of engagement with chat too, which is certainly down from when I started and was at that point already significantly down from earlier peaks

Comment: I agree there is a missed oportunity on the side bar that is causing Meta posts to go largely ignored. There is lots of wasted space in (for me) [empty boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2dJD.png) for *"Custom Filters"*, *"Watched Tags"* and *"Ignored Tags"* that could be used to highlight posts in Meta and on the main site, like featured Q&A or close-to-expire bounties. Meta needs more attention than it's currently receiving.

Comment: So this "discussion" is moving nowhere, among other things, because meta.mathematica  doesn't have significant traffic and engagement. What is the procedure to scale this up, should we at least try to articulate a solid point to be posted on meta.stackechange?

Comment: @rhermans "We don't need Featured on Meta, we need Featured on Mathematica.Meta"?